# Eway Rapid 3.1 integration for Magento EE

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

Is there any extensions available for integrating Rapid 3.1 payment for Magento enterprise version 1.12.0?

Comment: https://www.eway.com.au/app/magento ?